# How to merge two built-in Record types in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to merge two built-in Record types in typescript?

Let's say we have the following Records.

```js
var dictionary1 : Record<string, string []> ={
    'fruits' : ['apple','banana', 'cherry'],
    'vegetables' : ['cucumber','onion']
};

var dictionary2 : Record<string, string []> ={
    'fruits' : ['apple','banana', 'orange', 'pear'],
    'vegetables' : ['cucumber','corn'],
    'beverages' : ['soda']
};
```

I would like to merge them, and see the following result:

```js
var mergedDictionary : Record<string, string []> ={
    'fruits' : ['apple','banana', 'cherry', 'orange', 'pear'],
    'vegetables' : ['cucumber','onion', 'corn'],
    'beverages' : ['soda']
};
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I have tried to merge them by using the spread operator, like `mergedDictionary = [...dictionary1, ...dictionary2]`, but the result is not what I expect.

Comment: They're objects, not arrays. But you'll also need to write code that merges the individual arrays and removes the duplicates. There is no simple built-in solution for this.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for the response. I thought there is a built-in solution for it. I will try a different approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution - I did not check for performances though

[See on typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgS2FB4CGAnAngRhgLhgCUBTUDOAHmgwTAHMAaGGu%20mAbQF0A%20GAXgDeAKBhiYAcgBmGAK4IoECQU4S0AB3UAbEhMYSARmjDG0eycAAWJDNgldGo8RIBuJeiShoDOpSo4SwLJBALYGNnoS4Khg9o7ikiEkaIoShAHhJFL2wgC%20ANzCwqCQsIjIMZhYAEwqpORUrAzMTezcfEJOYtJyCn7papo6kUYmJuZRGMYeE%20rJGHFdkm4eXj4k-apBoeEL%20uSxDkuGJG5THpsBECBwZlx5hcXg0DBJGB5whPUgFNRQtM0WP82JxeAJOOUUOhsDhmJDKthqvcAHQYEhwYIkAAUWMwGDhSAAlAI%20CIEiUXrJ1LcoOjwQB5AwAKzIUGRAGsSFgIFjyoTUejMTi0MxOVhifxSTA0VBZBgwDBBDBkSqRZwxVx0irkWASAB3GAAZU8WI42txHA1MAAPtbQYTmNrypauVwuISuAUYLlmHjCYUEjK5Qqldq8Y6VVSaXSCnlmIJcjA0BBiGQfo1gYDWu1-UUKSAdMitCB6FilW8Pt7c0A)

```js
const dictionary1 : Record<string, string []> ={
    'fruits' : ['apple','banana', 'cherry'],
    'vegetables' : ['cucumber','onion'],
    'meats': ['beef']
};

const dictionary2 : Record<string, string []> ={
    'fruits' : ['apple','banana', 'orange', 'pear'],
    'vegetables' : ['cucumber','corn'],
    'beverages' : ['soda']
};

const merged: Record<string, string []> = [dictionary1, dictionary2]
.reduce((arr, dic) => {
    const updated = Object.keys(dic).reduce((a, key) => { return { ...a, [key]: [...new Set([...(a[key] || []), ...dic[key]])]}; }, arr);
    return { ...arr, ...updated };
}, {} as Record<string, string[]>);

console.log({ merged });
```

- the first `reduce` will merge the keys of the dictionaries
- for each key, you need to merge the content of the arrays
- the second reduce will merge the arrays for each key
- if the key does not exist in the source map, we use a hack `(a[key] || [])`to return an empty array
- to prevent duplicates, we use a set that we destructure back to an array `[...new Set(/* merged arrays */)]`

And the result:

```json
{
  "merged": {
    "fruits": [
      "apple",
      "banana",
      "cherry",
      "orange",
      "pear"
    ],
    "vegetables": [
      "cucumber",
      "onion",
      "corn"
    ],
    "meats": [
      "beef"
    ],
    "beverages": [
      "soda"
    ]
  }
}
```